# Error code: 0x80070035. The network path was not found. AND 0x80070043 The network name cannot be found

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, macbook

The first error shows when clicking in the icon of the computer I'm trying to access (MacBookPro) in Network browser. It takes some time and shows the error. The second is shown when I try to access through run \[MacBook name].
I followed all the solutions in https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/error-code-0x80070035-the-network-path-was-not-found-solved/ but no help.
On Cmd, net view and ping work, though. The computer is in the network (also the fact that it's showing an icon with name in network browser means it should be available).
It worked some time ago, but now it doesn't.
Any help very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access a MacOS share from Windows, a samba share has to be set. Verify if the samba share is still configured (you said it worked before) by following the [Apple Documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1657/mac). And then follow this [Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1658/10.15/mac/10.15) in order to connect to the share.

Comment: Thank you Darius for kicking in. I have done that before, as you noticed, I had it working previously. I double checked that the smb protocol is loaded on windows, I checked the credentials in windows and mac (refreshed both, although it hasn't ask me for password this time), file sharing in mac (afp and smb with user authentication), and if you check the article I used before coming here, it has 8 possible solutions which I did, in addition to others I found in other places.